# sum rows with condition and groupby

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe below:

| A | B | Percent | Groupby |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 0 | 10 | All |
| 2 | 1 | 5 | All |
| 2 | 2 | 6 | All |
| 2 | 0 | 20 | Type A |
| 2 | 1 | 15 | Type A |
| 2 | 2 | 8 | Type A |
| 3 | 0 | 10 | All |
| 3 | 1 | 5 | All |
| 3 | 2 | 6 | All |
| 3 | 3 | 3 | All |
| 3 | 0 | 20 | Type A |
| 3 | 1 | 15 | Type A |
| 3 | 2 | 8 | Type A |
| 3 | 3 | 11 | Type A |
| 4 | 0 | 10 | All |
| 4 | 1 | 5 | All |
| 4 | 2 | 6 | All |
| 4 | 3 | 3 | All |
| 4 | 4 | 1 | All |
| 4 | 0 | 20 | Type A |
| 4 | 1 | 15 | Type A |
| 4 | 2 | 8 | Type A |
| 4 | 3 | 11 | Type A |
| 4 | 4 | 2 | Type A |

I would like to get this result:

| A | B | Percent | Groupby | sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 0 | 10 | All | 10 |
| 2 | 1 | 5 | All | 11 |
| 2 | 2 | 6 | All | 11 |
| 2 | 0 | 20 | Type A | 20 |
| 2 | 1 | 15 | Type A | 23 |
| 2 | 2 | 8 | Type A | 23 |
| 3 | 0 | 10 | All | 15 |
| 3 | 1 | 5 | All | 15 |
| 3 | 2 | 6 | All | 9 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 | All | 9 |
| 3 | 0 | 20 | Type A | 35 |
| 3 | 1 | 15 | Type A | 35 |
| 3 | 2 | 8 | Type A | 19 |
| 3 | 3 | 11 | Type A | 19 |
| 4 | 0 | 10 | All | 15 |
| 4 | 1 | 5 | All | 15 |
| 4 | 2 | 6 | All | 10 |
| 4 | 3 | 3 | All | 10 |
| 4 | 4 | 1 | All | 10 |
| 4 | 0 | 20 | Type A | 35 |
| 4 | 1 | 15 | Type A | 35 |
| 4 | 2 | 8 | Type A | 21 |
| 4 | 3 | 11 | Type A | 21 |
| 4 | 4 | 2 | Type A | 21 |

The calculation is groupby "Groupby"

- if Col A is 2 then percent is summed for Col B with values of 1 and 2.
- if Col A is 3 then percent is summed for Col B with values of 0 and 1, and 2 and 3.
- if Col A is 4 then percent is summed for Col B with values of 0 and 1, and 2, 3, and 4.

Is there a quick way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean by "values 1 and 2". Do you mean the first and second values in a group?

Comment: @Mark: I meant the sum is only for Col B with value of 1 and 2 when Col A is 2.

Comment: okay, i see now. So if A == 2 and (B==1 or B==2), then sum = (A==2, B==1)'s percent column, + (A==2, B==2)'s percent column?

Comment: That is correct, Mark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your edit, it can be interesting to change the strategy. What you should do is to create subgroups for each condition:

```
conds = [
#   (2, [0]),
    (2, [1, 2]),
    (3, [0, 1]),
    (3, [2, 3]),
    (4, [0, 1]),
    (4, [2, 3, 4]),
]

# Create subgroups according your conditions
g = sum([i * (df['A'].eq(a) & df['B'].isin(b))
           for i, (a, b) in enumerate(conds, 1)]).mask(lambda x: x==0)

# Same with np.select
# masks = [(df['A'].eq(a) & df['B'].isin(b)) for a, b in conds]
# choices = 1 + np.arange(len(masks))
# g = np.select(masks, choices, default=np.nan)

# Group by A and Groupby columns and your new subgroups
df['sum'] = (df.groupby(['A', 'Groupby', g])['Percent']
               .transform('sum').fillna(df['Percent']))
```

Note: in fact, to avoid `fillna`, you can be explicit and append `(2, [0])` to the condition list to match every combinations.

The output is now:

```
>>> df
    A  B  Percent Groupby   sum
0   2  0       10     All  10.0
1   2  1        5     All  11.0
2   2  2        6     All  11.0
3   2  0       20  Type A  20.0
4   2  1       15  Type A  23.0
5   2  2        8  Type A  23.0
6   3  0       10     All  15.0
7   3  1        5     All  15.0
8   3  2        6     All   9.0
9   3  3        3     All   9.0
10  3  0       20  Type A  35.0
11  3  1       15  Type A  35.0
12  3  2        8  Type A  19.0
13  3  3       11  Type A  19.0
14  4  0       10     All  15.0
15  4  1        5     All  15.0
16  4  2        6     All  10.0
17  4  3        3     All  10.0
18  4  4        1     All  10.0
19  4  0       20  Type A  35.0
20  4  1       15  Type A  35.0
21  4  2        8  Type A  21.0
22  4  3       11  Type A  21.0
23  4  4        2  Type A  21.0
```

And subgroups:

```
>>> g
0     NaN
1     1.0
2     1.0
3     NaN
4     1.0
5     1.0
6     2.0
7     2.0
8     3.0
9     3.0
10    2.0
11    2.0
12    3.0
13    3.0
14    4.0
15    4.0
16    5.0
17    5.0
18    5.0
19    4.0
20    4.0
21    5.0
22    5.0
23    5.0
dtype: float64
```

---

**Old answer**

EDIT: As suggested by @jezrael, you can avoid to write all conditions by using a mapping dict and a comprehension:

You can use [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) to match your conditions then use [`groupby_transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) to broadcast the sum on right rows:

```
# conds = [df['A'] == 2,
#          df['A'] == 3,
#          df['A'] == 4]

# choices = [df['Percent'].where(df['B'].isin([1, 2])),
#            df['Percent'].where(df['B'].isin([2, 3])),
#            df['Percent'].where(df['B'].isin([2, 3, 4]))]

# Equivalent to
dmap = {2: [1, 2], 3: [2, 3], 4: [2, 3, 4]}

#                       conds --v           choices --v
conds, choices = zip(*[(df['A'] == k, df['Percent'].where(df['B'].isin(v)))
                       for k, v in dmap.items()])


df['sum'] = np.select(conds, choices)

df['sum'] = (df.mask(df['sum'].isna())
               .groupby(['Groupby', 'A'])['sum']
               .transform('sum').fillna(df['Percent']))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    A  B  Percent Groupby   sum
0   2  0       10     All  10.0
1   2  1        5     All  11.0
2   2  2        6     All  11.0
3   2  0       20  Type A  20.0
4   2  1       15  Type A  23.0
5   2  2        8  Type A  23.0
6   3  0       10     All  10.0
7   3  1        5     All   5.0
8   3  2        6     All   9.0
9   3  3        3     All   9.0
10  3  0       20  Type A  20.0
11  3  1       15  Type A  15.0
12  3  2        8  Type A  19.0
13  3  3       11  Type A  19.0
14  4  0       10     All  10.0
15  4  1        5     All   5.0
16  4  2        6     All  10.0
17  4  3        3     All  10.0
18  4  4        1     All  10.0
19  4  0       20  Type A  20.0
20  4  1       15  Type A  15.0
21  4  2        8  Type A  21.0
22  4  3       11  Type A  21.0
23  4  4        2  Type A  21.0
```

After `np.select`, the result is:

```
>>> df['sum']
0      NaN
1      5.0
2      6.0
3      NaN
4     15.0
5      8.0
6      NaN
7      NaN
8      6.0
9      3.0
10     NaN
11     NaN
12     8.0
13    11.0
14     NaN
15     NaN
16     6.0
17     3.0
18     1.0
19     NaN
20     NaN
21     8.0
22    11.0
23     2.0
Name: sum, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you +1. Would you mind modifying the codes to also sum the other rows instead of assigning the values from the Col percent? I have just edited the question.

Comment: @Jason. Why 30 and 35 for (3, 0, Type A) and (3, 1, Type B)? And not only 35?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It should be 35. I have made the change.

Comment: I updated my answer according your request. I removed `np.select` and used another strategy.

Comment: I also updated my answer with the alternative with `np.select`. Now you have the choice :)

Answer (score 2):

For avoid specify many conditions create dictionary for mapping `A` and `B` groups, convert to `DataFrame` and use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with `right` join, so possible create `sum`s per groups to new column in [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) only if match condition by [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
d = {2:[1,2], 3:[2,3], 4:[2,3,4]}


df = pd.DataFrame([(k, x) for k, v in d.items() for x in v],
                  columns=['A','B']).merge(df, how='right', indicator=True)

m = df.pop('_merge').eq('both')
df['sum'] = np.where(m, 
                     df.groupby(['Groupby', 'A', m])['Percent'].transform('sum'),
                     df['Percent'])
```

---

```
print (df)
    A  B  Percent Groupby  sum
0   2  0       10     All   10
1   2  1        5     All   11
2   2  2        6     All   11
3   2  0       20  Type A   20
4   2  1       15  Type A   23
5   2  2        8  Type A   23
6   3  0       10     All   10
7   3  1        5     All    5
8   3  2        6     All    9
9   3  3        3     All    9
10  3  0       20  Type A   20
11  3  1       15  Type A   15
12  3  2        8  Type A   19
13  3  3       11  Type A   19
14  4  0       10     All   10
15  4  1        5     All    5
16  4  2        6     All   10
17  4  3        3     All   10
18  4  4        1     All   10
19  4  0       20  Type A   20
20  4  1       15  Type A   15
21  4  2        8  Type A   21
22  4  3       11  Type A   21
23  4  4        2  Type A   21
```